# Somar e subtrair checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

tenho esse grupo de inputs e preciso que quando marcados eles somem os valores e quando desmarcados subtraiam

```html
   <div class="servicos" style= "justify-content: space-around; padding-left: 50px;">

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="119" id="customCheck_brasil" onclick="tribunais_estaduais(), brasil()">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_brasil">Brasil</label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  value="12" id="customCheck_reg_norte" onclick="regiao_norte()">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_reg_norte" >Região Norte</label>
        </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="30" id="customCheck_reg_nordeste" onclick="regiao_nordeste()">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_reg_nordeste">Região Nordeste</label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="11" id="regiao_centro_oeste" onclick="reg_centro_oeste()">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="regiao_centro_oeste">Região Centro-Oeste</label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="15" id="customCheck_sudeste" onclick="regiao_sudeste()">
          <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_sudeste">Região Sudeste</label>
      </div>

      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="8" id="customCheck_reg_sul" onclick="regiao_sul()">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_reg_sul">Região Sul</label>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  value="60" id="customCheck_trib_est" onclick="tribunais_estaduais(),trib_estaduais()">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_trib_est" >Tribunais Estaduais</label>
          </div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="8" id="customCheck_trib_fed" onclick="tribunais_federais(), trib_federais()">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_trib_fed">Tribunais Federais</label>
        </div>

        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  value="3" onclick="tribunais_superiores(), trib_superiores()" id="customCheck_trib_sup">
            <label class="custom-control-label"  for="customCheck_trib_sup">Tribunais Superiores</label>
        </div>
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="15" id="customCheck_trib_trab" onclick="tribunais_trabalhistas(), trib_trabalhistas()">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_trib_trab">Tribunais Trabalhistas</label>
        </div>

<div class="botao_calc" id="sistemas">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" onblur="">
    Sistemas Monitorados <span class="badge badge-light" id="qtde_sistemas">0<label for="" ></label></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

tentei esse script

```js
  var tribunais_estaduais = 60;
  var tribunais_federais = 41;
  var tribunais_superiores = 3;
  var tribunais_trabalhistas = 15;
  
  var sistemas = document.getElementById('qtde_sistemas');

  if(customCheck_trib_est.checked == true) {
    sistemas.innerHTML = tribunais_estaduais;
  }else{
    sistemas.innerHTML = tribunais_estaduais - tribunais_estaduais
  }
  if(customCheck_trib_fed.checked == true) {
    sistemas.innerHTML = tribunais_federais;
  }else{
    sistemas.innerHTML = tribunais_federais - tribunais_federais;
  }
  if(customCheck_trib_sup.checked == true) {
    sistemas.innerHTML = tribunais_superiores;
  }else{
    sistemas.innerHTML = tribunais_superiores - tribunais_superiores;
  }
  if(customCheck_trib_trab.checked == true) {
    sistemas.innerHTML = tribunais_trabalhistas;
  }else{
    sistemas.innerHTML = tribunais_trabalhistas - tribunais_trabalhistas;
  }
```

Comment: Tentou desenvolver algum script??

Comment: cara tentei, mas $(':checkbox').click(function() {
  //Atribui o valor do input p/ variável 'valor'
  var valor = parseInt($(this).val());
  //Se o checkbox for marcado ele soma se não subtrai
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
    total += valor;
  } else {
    total -= valor;
  }
 //Atribui o valor ao input
  $('qtde_sistemas').val(total);
});

Comment: se alguma resposta serviu marque como aceita, veja como https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png

Answer (score 1):

```js
//evento de alteração nos inputs checkbox
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
  //altera o valor #total ao marcar/desmarcar os checkbox
  $("#total").val(function() {
    //declarar uma variável para manter a soma dos valores
    var sum = 0;
    //Iteração para somar os valores das caixas de seleção marcadas
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
      sum += ~~$(this).val();
    });
    return sum;
  });
});

//coloquei essas functions que não fazem absolutamente nada para não dar erro no executar.
function tribunais_estaduais(){};
function brasil(){};
function regiao_norte(){};
function regiao_nordeste(){};
function reg_centro_oeste(){};
function regiao_sudeste(){};
function regiao_sul(){};
function tribunais_estaduais(){};
function trib_estaduais(){};
function tribunais_federais(){};
function trib_federais(){};
function tribunais_superiores(){};
function trib_superiores(){};
function tribunais_trabalhistas(){};
function trib_trabalhistas(){};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="servicos" style= "justify-content: space-around; padding-left: 50px;">

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="119" id="customCheck_brasil" onclick="tribunais_estaduais(), brasil()">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_brasil">Brasil</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  value="12" id="customCheck_reg_norte" onclick="regiao_norte()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_reg_norte" >Região Norte</label>
    </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="30" id="customCheck_reg_nordeste" onclick="regiao_nordeste()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_reg_nordeste">Região Nordeste</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="11" id="regiao_centro_oeste" onclick="reg_centro_oeste()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="regiao_centro_oeste">Região Centro-Oeste</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="15" id="customCheck_sudeste" onclick="regiao_sudeste()">
      <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_sudeste">Região Sudeste</label>
  </div>

  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="8" id="customCheck_reg_sul" onclick="regiao_sul()">
    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_reg_sul">Região Sul</label>
</div>

<div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  value="60" id="customCheck_trib_est" onclick="tribunais_estaduais(),trib_estaduais()">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_trib_est" >Tribunais Estaduais</label>
      </div>

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="8" id="customCheck_trib_fed" onclick="tribunais_federais(), trib_federais()">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_trib_fed">Tribunais Federais</label>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input"  value="3" onclick="tribunais_superiores(), trib_superiores()" id="customCheck_trib_sup">
        <label class="custom-control-label"  for="customCheck_trib_sup">Tribunais Superiores</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" value="15" id="customCheck_trib_trab" onclick="tribunais_trabalhistas(), trib_trabalhistas()">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck_trib_trab">Tribunais Trabalhistas</label>
    </div>
    <input id="total" name='total' readonly='readonly'>
```

coloquei as funcions para não dar erro no executar mas você deve ter elas ai.